# i need to create a file and it's not creating and i'm getting an error

Tags: java, file-handling

```
File file = new File("Skill.txt");

Scanner new_sc;
try {
    new_sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (new_sc.hasNextLine())
        System.out.println(new_sc.nextLine());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used the try catch method and I'm not familiar with this method.

Comment: You title and your code seem to be opposite - your code is reading a file

Comment: BTW, please post your stacktrace

Comment: If your problem is that your code prints `FileNotFoundException` and a bunch of line information, that's because that's what `e.printStackTrace()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is for reading from file. but if you want to create ,write and read from a file:

You can try something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Helper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File fout = new File("Skill.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
              //Writing to the file
              fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);     
              BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
              bw.write("Writing to the file ...");
              bw.newLine();
              bw.close();

              //Reading from file
              Scanner new_sc = new Scanner(fout);

              while (new_sc.hasNextLine())
                  System.out.println(new_sc.nextLine());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```